# While loop in kthread causes memory leak

Tags: kernel, scheduling, multithreading, memory-leaks

i'm working on a kernel (4.7.4) module which starts a kthread with a while loop. This while loop / kthread runs on a isolated cpu core (nohz_full=3 rcu_nocbs=3 isolcpus=3) as fast as possible and makes some complex stuff. Everything is working fine, but i recognized a kernel memory leak. Hence i used a very simple kthread for testing:

```
static int thread_function(void *data){

   while(stop_thread) rmb();

   return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately with the same result. Slabtop shows me, that dentry, filp and kmalloc-256 (sometimes kmalloc-64) allocate memory permanent, until my kthread is terminated. The following function calls are responsible:

- filp: get_empty_filp
- dentry: __d_alloc
- kmalloc-256: prepare_creds & copy_creds

I think it has to do with the RCU scheduler, but i have no clue where and how to search.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!